# natural log function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to input the follwing formula in excel

```
LN(0.198-2*0.14*142/62.32326*303.5141*20)
```

Excel does not allow negative numbers inside the natural log function so I have to input the equation as the natural log of the first function minus the natural log of the second function. 
 My calculator and Mathematica are giving me a value of around -1.6 while Excel is giving me a value of -9.8. Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong in excel? or the proper way of inputting this function? thank you.

Comment: "Excel does not allow negative numbers inside the natural log function" -that's not specific to Excel. How exactly you enter it in Mathematica? What exactly you need to calculate?...

Comment: you're reading the result incorrectly, or you've typed the expression wrong. logarithm can't be applied to non-positive numbers, unless complex numbers are allowed. Wolfram alpha gives the result [8.261636... + 3.141593... i](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LN(0.198-2*0.14*142%2F62.32326*303.5141*20))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter:

```
 =0.198-2*0.14*142/62.32326*303.5141*20
```

in a cell, you get:

```
 -3872.423752
```

and the log function will fail on this value:

[image]

If however you enter:

```
   =0.198-2*0.14*142/(62.32326*303.5141*20)
```

you will get:

```
   0.197894904
```

and Excel returns:

```
-1.620019179
```

from the `LN()` function.:

[image]

Just be sure your arithmetic expression correctly reflect the precedence of multiply/divide that you require.